# Run md5sum in script from root

Tags: linux, bash, shell, md5

I have a folder with a bash script to check the md5sum of my file system.

The problem is the auto generated md5 check file does not contain a leading forward slash. I believe we are generating the md5 check file using the md5sum utility. But, because my md5sum call is in a script not running in the root directory it cant find files using a relative paths `etc/boa.conf`.

The solution I have in mind is to run the test script from my test folder but inside the script tell bash to run the command in the root directory.

Here is what I have:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd "$(dirname "$0")"

md5sum -c /home/FileSystemCorruptionTest/*.chk > /home/FileSystemCorruptionTest/`date +%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S`.log

echo "" > /home/FileSystemCorruptionTest/Done
```

The change directory doesn't seem to work in my case...

Comment: I see nothing wrong with the `cd` line, are you sure it is not working? You do realize it just changes the folder inside the script (unless you start the script using `.`/`script` by which you are running it as if you were copy-pasting its content.
BTW, it might be better to loop through the FS or use `xargs`.

Comment: It runs but the md5sum script is not finding the files that are relative to root.. Says they dont exist when they do. If I run the md5sum command from root it works fine.

Comment: Why are you `cd`-ing to the directory of the script if you need the sums run from `/`? Why not `cd /`?

Comment: Yeah well I didn't fully understand that cd I had... I did just cd in `/`. Working now.